# How can I detect base64 encoded strings planted by bad guys?

Tags: php, base64

When investigating hacks, I occasionally see files that contain things like

```
<?php $_f__db='base'.(128/2).'_de'.'code';$_f__db=$_f__db(str_replace("\n", '',
'NrFujw3uBxuQgdlYFMmhRT5V9BI7aFnbviWhPbszFd2E/c3ZpFcl++i/D7YTZS/SS/UmjeX5iUwPas6c
lSM+lWVedpU7QjEjf4CDapQAkqXpaTvaQ3g247sz4HjqGhV71TFRk69+EctaM7tmymteKtT9OSwsSBmp
```

I'd love to just scan for "base64_decode", but the bad guys are obfuscating this - any ideas on detecting this sort of thing?

Comment: Occasionally see files like that where...? also `(128/2)` is amazing!

Comment: On websites that have been hacked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scanners for that like Lynis

```
# cd /opt/
# wget https://downloads.cisofy.com/lynis/lynis-2.6.6.tar.gz
# tar xvzf lynis-2.6.6.tar.gz
# mv lynis /usr/local/
# ln -s /usr/local/lynis/lynis /usr/local/bin/lynis
```

then use

```
lynis audit system
```

To scan the server

You can also use chkrootkit

```
# yum update
# yum install wget gcc-c++ glibc-static
# wget -c ftp://ftp.pangeia.com.br/pub/seg/pac/chkrootkit.tar.gz
# tar –xzf chkrootkit.tar.gz
# mkdir /usr/local/chkrootkit
# mv chkrootkit-0.52/* /usr/local/chkrootkit
# cd /usr/local/chkrootkit
# make sense
```

Then you do this to start a scan

```
sudo chkrootkit
```

Rkhunter is probably worth mentionning as well

```
# yum install epel-release
# yum install rkhunter
```

Then

```
rkhunter -c
```

To scan

You can also take a look at this project here.
https://github.com/jvoisin/php-malware-finder

It detects a lot of obfuscated/dodgy code.

There's others like ClamAV and LMD but any of the above will find most of the viruses. But nothing beats a human eye ;-) It's a good practice to keep an eye on server processes and new added files. If you don't need base64 you can always add that to PHP.ini as a blocked function.

Keep in mind that hackers will always have an edge on obfuscating because of the creative possibilities that modern coding offers ... There is nothing you can do about it other then using multiple tools and keep your guard up.

I have 4 auto scans on each of my servers and I also keep track of file changes and file uploads. If you where hoping for a one liner search code to do all, be desapointed. It's a nightmare that every security experts has to deal with. The best way to deal with viruses is by making sure they can't be uploaded in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Patrick's right:  you have to be sure that they can't be uploaded in the first place.

Your web servers should be running in well-isolated machines or containers which have *read-only* access to all of their files.  They should be invoking FastCGI services from machines that can't be reached from the outside world, which also have read-only access to all of their programming.  And, so on.

Don't expect `ssh` to protect you:  at the end of the day, "ssh is a *shell."*  You need much stronger, OpenVPN+certificates+tls_auth based security to both protect and conceal the administrative portals to your systems.